# Find out how many threads my application is running?

Tags: c#, multithreading

I'm trying to find out how many threads my application is running in order to make a live graph of the performance. Can you point me in the right direction or provide a code example? Thanks!

Comment: Do you want to know how many threads you've explicitly created?  Or any threads .NET may have created on your behalf as well?

Comment: How would knowing how many threads exist be related to performance? Surely what's interesting is what those threads are doing.

Comment: @David Heffernan: I was trying to find a way of doing this as well. Mainly I was looking to log how many threads were in the aplication over time to analyze how the program was handling its thread generation/releasing and I was hoping to find a rhyme or reason as to why the number of threads(as shown in the task manager) would be growing ridiculously high. So this could be related to performance from that stand point.

Answer (score 45):

You may take a look at the [Threads](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.threads.aspx) property of the current process:

```
System.Diagnostics.Process.GetCurrentProcess().Threads
```

Of course this includes unmanaged threads as well.

Comment: Specifying the Assembly and namespace for something that is not included by default in a C# project would make the answer more complete. `Process` is in the `System.Diagnostics` namespace.

Comment: @Darin Dimitrove is there any way to find out that 'Which thread belong to which section of program?'

Answer (score 2):

**If you want to see only Managed Threads:**

When you debug your application from Visual Studio you could also check out the `Threads` and `Parallel Stacks` window, 
which can be found in the menu under `Debug -> Windows`

You can see the `Thread-Count` (marked green) in the top `Threads` window in the picture below

[image]

Comment: Due to the large number of threads, some functionality was disabled to maintain debugging performance. Please restart Visual Studio to re-enable grouping.

Answer (score -1):

```
private static int s_threadCount;

private static void MyMethod() {
  Interlocked.Increment(ref s_threadCount);
  try {
    ...
  } finally {
    Interlocked.Decrement(ref s_threadCount);
  }
}
```

Comment: That would only tell you the number of threads in that particular method, not the number of threads for the process as a whole.